# Is it possible to use my monitor as a HDTV?

Tags: display, tv

I have Airtel DTH HD+ connection  and a old TV but I also have a Samsung LCD monitor with only a VGA port and no audio port. My set top box has 2 USB (for recording purposes), 1 HDMI port and 1 RCA port (Red,yellow and white).

Also my set top box is HDCP compliant. Is it possible to use my Samsung monitor to use as a HDTV so I can enjoy HD channels? If it is possible then please tell me how?

Comment: Yes, just make sure that you use an HDMI-to-VGA converter that supports HDCP.  E.G. the converter uses a [EP9851](http://www.epmi.com.tw/sayapro03.php?id=17) chip.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get an HDMI to VGA converter - this will allow you to take the video signal from your set top box to your monitor.

However, VGA does not carry an audio signal - If your monitor only has a VGA port and no audio port then you will not be able to have audio via the VGA cable.  Unless you can plug speakers into your set top box you will not be able to hear the sound.

UPDATE:  However you should be able to get an HDMI to VGA converter with an audio port for your speakers, as pointed out in the comments bellow.

Comment: Many adapters for HDMI to VGA have a separate audio output from the HDMI source to connect speakers or other audio device to, such as this one just as an example http://www.amazon.com/Portta-PETHV-converter-Converter-Windows-10/dp/B003O55U8K

Comment: *"get a simple VGA to HD converter"* -- You have it backwards.  *"If your monitor only has a VGA port and no audio port then you will not be able to have audio via the VGA cable."* -- You're stating a bogus dependency.

Comment: Good points, I had not considered an audio output on the converter itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Samsung monitor has no HDMI or DVI port, it will be very difficult to connect your set-top box to your monitor. There are HDMI to VGA converters but most likely won't work due to HDCP protection.

Comment: *"There are HDMI to VGA converters but most likely won't work..."* -- Actually it's not that hard to convert.  I have a low-cost HDMI-to-VGA converter, and it can handle HDCP 1.2. It uses a [EP9851](http://www.epmi.com.tw/sayapro03.php?id=17) chip.